# Create Property in Java and in C file

Tags: java, android, c, properties

I am currently faced with the current situation:

I would like to create a toggle for the Double Tap to Wake gesture which is "turned on" with the following commit to the Nexus 6 PowerHAL: https://gerrit.omnirom.org/#/c/13930/1/power/power_shamu.c

I would like to achieve this by using a system app (written in java) to provide a toggle to enable/disable this feature (written to the kernel sysfs path in the above C file).

Clearly, I cannot just wrap it in an ifdef or anything, but I am told that I can create a property in the app (Java file) and then inherit it in the C file.

Theoretically this will function as follows:

- Enable/Disable feature in app (Java sets property to on or off)
- Property is used by C file to determine what value to write to the sysfs path

The content of the sysfs file will be as simple as comparing values of the file between enabled and disabled, I am more concerned with the logic involved in accomplishing this.

I know very little Java but have a solid foundation of C++.

I did some Google searching and wasn't able to find anything relevant.

Any insight would be great.

-- Jake

Comment: Be careful, C and C++ are not the same thing!

Comment: Linux kernel features are often controlled by writing files in sysfs, and you don't need C to do that. What do you want to use C for?

Answer (score 0):

Android NDK has everything you need

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("library");
    }

    /**
     * Native method implemented in C/C++
     */
    public native String toggleFoo();
}
```

---

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_package_MyActivity_toggleFoo(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```